# pytest logs parsing in logstash

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I have some pytest logs to process.

example of the log line is

```
"== 5 failed, 2 passed, 11 deselected, 7 xfailed, 2 xpassed in 1155.95 seconds =="
```

I need to filter this type of log lines and make key value pairs as below failed

```
passed=2,deselected=11and xfailed=7
```

Please help me to write filter in logstash config file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't provide any information that you've tried to do this yourself, but...

The general idea is to use the grok{} filter to parse the line into fields.  Here's a start:

```
grok {
    match => [ "message", "== %{NUMBER:failed} failed," ]
}
```

This will create a field called 'failed' that would contain the value '5' from your sample data.  Continue that idea with the other interesting data.